# Find maximum of a function when its integral is known

Tags: statistics, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

A very open question: have people considered a problem where the integral of a function is known (or we know a bound on it), and the goal is to find the location of its maximum?

Does this pop up in any applications?

Comment: why do you ask ... is there something you're working with like this?

Comment: Well, if you can integrate the function on subintervals of its domain there should be something to say... If $f$ is a continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$, you can partition this interval into intervals $[a_{n,i},b_{n,i}]$ of diameter $\leq(1/n)$. Choose $i(n)$ s.t. the integral of $[a_{n,i(n)},b_{n,i(n)}]$ is maximum amongst those small intervals. I am pretty sure there should be a subsequence of $\{i(n)\}_n$ s.t. $\{a_{i(n)}\}$ will converge to a point of maximum of $f$.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me if maximum refers to the function or its integral or if integral refers to the functions anti-derivative or a specific definite integral.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems you are asking "is there an application to the fundamental theorem of calculus?". You say the integral is known, so assuming sufficient regularity, you have something like

$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(y)dy, \quad a\in[-\infty,\infty]$$

and you want to maximize this, so you compute 
$$F'(x) = f(x)$$

So that any extrema of $F$ are simply the zeros of $f$. Or if your question is to maximize $f$ given $F$, then you look at the zeros of
$$F''(x) = f'(x)$$
Let me know if I am interpreting you question correctly.

Note that one application of this is when $F$ is a cumulative distribution function and $f$ is a probability density (and $a=-\infty$). Then values in a neighborhood of the maximum of $f$ have the greatest probability of occuring.